# How to change logback log level programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, logback

I have some performance unit tests that create an unreasonable amount of logs that I don't really care for and are actually impacting performance. Can I somehow raise the log level in logback in the Before method for that unit test only (and restore it in After)? Or is there a better way of addressing that?

Answer (score 65):

This works for me:

```
public static void setLoggingLevel(Level level) {
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.setLevel(level);
}
```

Then in your test, if you want all levels for example:

```
setLoggingLevel(Level.ALL);
```

Comment: It is just sloppy programming that the makers of these applications don't provide an API to set the log level and instead force the user to go find the implementation that is in use.

Comment: Fully agree with that!

Comment: Hi, I'm testing this solution and I it works if you initially are in DEBUG mode for example and you set to ERROR level, but if you initially are in ERROR mode and you try to set to DEBUG mode, it seems not working.Thanks....