# Less logs in tests both in IDE and with Maven

Tags: java, testing, logging, log4j

Similarly to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627358/how-to-change-logback-log-level-programmatically-in-java) - I want less logs in my tests outputs. Difference - I'm not using `slf4j`, I'm still on `log4j`.

- there are loud libraries I want silenced without filtering each in log properties
- there are DEBUG and INFO level logs I don't care in tests, (unless I do - rare).
- this I want to work both in IDE and Maven, including running tests from IDE, and via Maven

First, like in the linked question, I can do this "per test": 
  `@Before`, increase log level, `@After`, decrease it to normal.

That is per test, sooner or later someone will forget it.

I can set up Surefire properties, but that works for Surefire. Also, I use FailSafe for integration tests, so am wondering if I would have to set this up separately?

The other possibility is to filter out loud libraries. I did that for some, but that means each time I'll have to filter another one again.

Finally, I can set up log4j per directories, which means for each project, for test dir, different log config.

Is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Maven 2 and 3 have logging level hard-coded (in the source). So, filtering and log4j per dir is the way to go.